# rewriterule transparent QSA

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use the bellow code to rewrite TRANSPARENTLY from anything.sitename.com/search to sitename.com/folder/index.php?id=search, thats works but **redirect** instead of **transparent** (QSA) rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.sitename\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://sitename.com/folder/index.php?id=%1 [L,QSA]
```

also only %1 are exist and refer to request_uri(instead of subdomain), and %2 variable is not set.
any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `http://` from target URI otherwise it will be redirect instead of rewrite.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.sitename\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?id=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I get your problem. Apache is redirecting external instead of internal, right? That's because you passed a domain. You have to use filepaths to tell apache to use internal redirects.